# change the caption regularly in jqGrid on gave sumbit button? on ($(document).ready(function())

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

in my project i have to display the selected state as a caption in jqGrid. but `$(document).ready(function()` show the first value only in the jqGrid. how i change the next value in the jqGrid on the (`$(document).ready(function()`).

`$(document).ready(function()`, it will load the first condition only how i can get the next values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    current_search = $('#search_type').val();
    var Statevalue = $('#stateId').val(); 
    alert('ss'+Statevalue);
    var tableheadings="";

    if(Statevalue=='MD')
    {
        tableheadings = 'Maryland' ;
    }
    else if(Statevalue=='DC')
    {
        tableheadings= 'District Of Columbia';
    }else
    {
        tableheadings='Virginia';
    }
```

in this it will done the `'MD'` only in `$(document).ready(function()`. how i will and set the caption for `dc` and `vr`.

my caption syntax:

```
$("#list1").jqGrid('setCaption',
    'Incident Listing By Congressional District :' + tableheadings);
```

i need how to access the next values in the `$(document).ready(function()`.

Comment: Many things are stay unclear from the text of your question: Where you create jqGrid? Where you call `setCaption`? How HTML looks like especially controls like `#stateId`, how it will be filled? Do you use some events like `change` event handler on the `#stateId` to change title of jqGrid on every change of `#stateId`? It's important to understand **the order of execution of the fragments of the code**. You wrote in the title of your question about some "submit button". Which button you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this on load complete action of jqgrid. Think of it like this. Your jqgrid gets loaded after dom ready and once its complete you can run a function onLoadComplete and change caption. 
If you do before load complete then jqgrid will replace it.